# Concatenation between rows

Tags: r, string-concatenation, data-manipulation

I have a dataframe with two colmns:

```
C1 <- c("abcd > de > efg", "hij > kl > iiii", "aa", "a > bbb")
C2 <- c("1980","1982","1989","1989")

df <- data.frame(C1, C2, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

My goal is concatenate the arguments of the 2 of them like this:

```
result <- c("1980abcd > 1980de > 1980efg", "1982hij > 1982kl > 1982iiii", "1989aa", "1989a > 1989bbb")
```

How can i do that? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way via base R is to use split the `C1` vector and use `mapply` to paste with `C2`, i.e.

```
v1 <- mapply(function(x, y) paste(paste0(x, y), collapse = ' > '), C2, strsplit(C1, ' > '))

unname(v1)
#[1] "1980abcd > 1980de > 1980efg" "1982hij > 1982kl > 1982iiii" "1989aa"   "1989a > 1989bbb"
```

**NOTE:** The result of `mapply` (i.e. `v1`) is a named vector. Hence I used `unname` to get to your desired structure. However, note that a named vector is still a vector and will behave as such.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an approach that doesn't require splitting each string and pasting back together:

```
mapply(function(x,y) gsub("(^|\\s)(?=[a-z]+)",  paste0("\\1", y), x, perl = TRUE), 
                     df$C1, df$C2, USE.NAMES = FALSE)
#[1] "1980abcd > 1980de > 1980efg" "1982hij > 1982kl > 1982iiii"
#[3] "1989aa"                      "1989a > 1989bbb"
```

The regular expression pattern `(^|\\s)(?=[a-z]+)` matches either the beginning of the string or a space followed by a lower case character and then replaces it with the corresponding C2-entry.

---

Here's a purrr alternative:

```
library(purrr)
strsplit(df$C1, " > ") %>% map2_chr(df$C2, ~paste(.y, .x, sep = "", collapse=" > "))
#[1] "1980abcd > 1980de > 1980efg" "1982hij > 1982kl > 1982iiii"
#[3] "1989aa"                      "1989a > 1989bbb"
```

Comment: Nice one. I tried that as well but I am regex-blind :)

Comment: @Sotos, thanks, took some time to figure out but it was fun.

Answer (score 0):

Using strsplit, apply and paste :

```
    library(dplyr)
    df <- tibble(C1=strsplit(C1," > "),C2)

    res <- unlist(apply(df,1,function(y){paste(paste(x$C2,x$C1,sep=""),collapse=" > ")}))
    # [1] "1980abcd > 1980de > 1980efg" "1982hij > 1982kl > 1982iiii" "1989aa"                     
    # [4] "1989a > 1989bbb"
```

Comment: Why do you load `dplyr` just to make a tibble? What is wrong with a data frame?

Comment: nothing's wrong with dataframes. I've just habits to use tibbles